# What does .(...) mean in a .prof report mean?

Tags: haskell, profiling

I'm looking for optimization oportunities in my Haskell program by compiling with `-prof`, but I don't know how to interpret the cost centres that contain ellipses. What are `filter.(...)` and `jankRoulette.select.(...)`?

```
COST CENTRE                MODULE                     %time %alloc

filter.(...)               Forest                      46.5   22.3
set-union                  Forest                      22.5    4.1
cache-lookup               Forest                      16.0    0.1
removeMany                 MultiMapSet                  3.7    1.9
insertMany                 MultiMapSet                  3.3    1.8
jankRoulette.select.(...)  Forest                       1.4   15.2
```

I generated that with: `$ ghc --make -rtsopts -prof -auto-all main.hs && ./main +RTS -p && cat main.prof`

The function `filter` has a few definitions in a `where` clause, like this:

```
filter a b = blahblah where
    foo = bar
    bar = baz
    baz = bing
```

But those all show up as `filter.foo`, `filter.bar`, etc.

I thought they might be nested let expressions, but `jankRoulette.select` doesn't have any. And I've added SCC directives in front of most of them without any of those cost centres rising to the top.

Since most of the time is spent in `filter.(...)`, I'd like to know what that is. :)

Comment: As the `TODO` comment in the code bennofs quotes should suggest, GHC profiler reports (and pretty much anything the compiler outputs) should always be accompanied by the result of `ghc --version`.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! For posterity, I happen to be running The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*TL; DR:* GHC generates this when you do a pattern match in a let binding, like `let (x,y) = c`. The cost of evaluating `c` is tracked by the `...` cost centre (since there is no unique name to it)`.

---

So how did I find this out?
A grep for `(...)` in the GHC source code finds the following (from compiler/deSugar/Coverage.hs):

```hs
-- TODO: Revisit this
addTickLHsBind (L pos (pat@(PatBind { pat_lhs = lhs, pat_rhs = rhs }))) = do
  let name = "(...)"
  (fvs, rhs') <- getFreeVars $ addPathEntry name $ addTickGRHSs False False rhs

   {- ... more code following, but not relevant to this purpose
   -}
```

That code tells us that it has to do something with pattern bindings.
So we can make a small test program to check the behavior:

```
x :: Int
(x:_) = reverse [1..1000000000]

main :: IO ()
main = print x
```

Then, we can run this program with profiling enabled. An indeed, GHC generates the following output:

```
COST CENTRE MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time 

%alloc
MAIN        MAIN                     42           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF        Main                     83           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  (...)     Main                     86           1  100.0  100.0   100.0  100.0
  x         Main                     85           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main      Main                     84           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

So it turns out the assumption made from the code was correct. All of the time of the program is spent evaluating the `reverse [1..1000000000]` expression, and it's assigned to the `(...)` cost centre.

Comment: I love (and totally sympathize with) the `TODO` comment there :P.

Comment: Corollary: to disambiguate the cost centres, name the values before pattern-matching, like `(x:_) = foo where foo = reverse [1..10000000]`. Great answer, bennofs, thanks a ton!